# Connect to EC2 mongo server

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-compass, studio3t

I have been facing this issue since so long. I want to connect to compass or any mongo GUI tool to EC2 mongo server. I have bind_ip 127.0.0.1 in mongo.conf and don't want to open for all IP. 
I have tried connecting to the server through SSH but get "MongoDB not running on the provided host and port" error. Please anyone can help to connect remotely to MongoDB server.

Comment: please check whether you  have open the port if not then login aws management console goto Security Group open the port of mongo

Comment: yes, already open the port in security group.

Comment: It gets connected when I change the bind_ip to 0.0.0.0. This solution I don't want to do. Because of it open to the whole internet

Comment: try running this `sudo nmap -Pn localhost` will check whether port is enabled on your server or not . use your server ip and port

Comment: I can see only HTTP, https, and ssh ports are open. But in the EC2 GUI, I can see 27017 port is open. How to open port for 27017 for EC2 instance

Comment: if you already have open the port using security group then login to your server using ssh and add  sudo ufw allow 27017

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174158/discussion-between-ritesh-kumar-agrahari-and-gaurav-singh).